# Collect leaves in general tree

Tags: tree, prolog

I'm trying to write a predicate `leaves/2` that collects all the leaves in a general tree in Prolog. I have a similar predicate for a binary tree, but I'm stuck in my attempts to generalize it for a multi-way or general tree (where a node can have an indefinite number of children). This is the one for a binary tree (in which leaf nodes are represented by `l(_)` ):

```
leaves( l(X), [X|T], T ).
leaves( tree(L,R), A, C ) :-
  leaves(L,A,B),
  leaves(R,B,C).
leaves(Tree,L) :-
  leaves(Tree,L,[]).
```

The query

```
leaves(tree(tree(l(3),l(2)),l(6)),Leaves)
```

correctly returns

```
Leaves = [3,2,6]
```

When I try to generalize this for a multi-way tree, I get stuck on the fact that a node contains an entire list of trees. I have tried to recursively 'unpack' such a tree list to then gradually process it with a variant of the above predicate, but it's not working, since I find it difficult to isolate the tree list from the node in order to process it separately.

So, a general tree could be a representation of a sentence, where each node contains a syntactic category and the leaves contain the actual words, like this:

```
tree( s, [ tree(np,[l(the),l(dog)]), tree(vp,[l(barks)]) ] )
```

A similar query with this general tree as an argument should then produce `Leaves=[the,dog,barks]`. I'm trying to find an implementation in the same style as for a binary tree, without using `append/2`, a DCG, or anything like that.

Comment: Have you tried doing with pen and paper first? In other words don't do it with code do it manually as you would if you were teaching it to someone. You would be amazed how many times that is helpful.

Comment: @GuyCoder Thanks, that certainly is a valuable tip. Unfortunately, I'm experiencing the same issue when trying it on paper. It's frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is as follows:

```
leaves(Tree, Leaves) :-
    leaves(Tree, [], Leaves).
  
leaves(l(X), L, [X|L]).

leaves(tree(_, Children), L0, L) :-
    leaves(Children, L0, L).

leaves([], L, L).

leaves([Child|Children], L0, L) :- 
    leaves(Children, L0, L1),
    leaves(Child, L1, L).
```

Example:

```
?- leaves(tree(s, [tree(np, [l(the), l(dog)]), tree(vp, [l(barks)])]), Leaves).
Leaves = [the, dog, barks].
```